# PHP upload file script

Tags: php, upload

**FIXED**

I was getting an error value of `2`.

This is the PHP upload script that I am using. Users are allowed to upload files with no restrictions. However, some .exe files fail to get uploaded while others work fine. 
I'm not sure what the problem is? 
(This script was taken from a PHP tutorial)

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 



$target_path = "uploads/upload.exe";


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<a href="http://localhost/Test/uploads/run.php">Continue</a>';

} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Any errors you receive?

Comment: ". Users are allowed to upload files with no restrictions" dangerous

Comment: $target_path = "uploads/upload.exe";   Whaaat?

Comment: @Dagon I know the risks, with having no restrictions. This is just for learning purposes.

Comment: @FreshPro File gets renamed to `upload.exe`. I was testing something.

Comment: How do you know some files fail to upload?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: Check the content of `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` before confirming the upload. Any errors should show up there.

Comment: Can you please just use debug to see what's the variable's values? So that you can see what is wrong

Comment: @FreshPro I get an error value of `2`

Comment: Error code #2 = UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE See documentation: [php.net/manual/file-upload.errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)